# Virtual Machine using vmware to get windows OS and sql server 2012?

Tags: macos, sql-server-2012, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

Does a VM affect computer performance when it is shut down? I'm about to be taking Database Administration, and we're going to be using SQL server 2012, and I have a macbook, and an iMac. My MacBook has an i7 2.whatever GHz quad core processor, 16GB RAM, 750SSD... Is there anything I should be worried about? And what is the best Windows OS to run on my mac, that is compatible with sql server? I've never used all of this stuff, and I heard VM is probably better on my machine. If it does affect the performance on my computer when it's shut down, what's the best way to maintain the integrity of my machine, regardless whether the performance issues carry on or not, I'd like to know any maintenance suggestions from you guys. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can ensure no resources except HDD space are used by shutting down your VM or even your VMware app when it's not in use.  Windows Server (take a pick) is best suited for SQL Server. You could try Server 2012 or 2008.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: @KenWhite Nobody said this was a programming question.

Comment: Then it's off-topic here. This site is for programming (code) and programmers tools (IDEs, compilers, specific API use, etc.) related questions. If you can't explain how it's a programming question, it doesn't belong here. When you created your account, you agreed to complete the [tour] and to review the pages in the [help]. Please do so before asking your next question here. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite Hey, thanks for the pointless comment. I am going to be using the VM for everything you just asked. I don't understand why I have to clarify that. You're off-topic here, so if you're not here to help, then please go ahead and avoid my question. If you really don't consider my windows VM as a programming tool for other programming tools, I'm not interested in what you have to say anyway.

Comment: It's not a *pointless comment*. We have specific guidelines regarding the types of question that are appropriate here, and users moderate the site. When you created your acount, you agreed to take the [tour] and review the [help] pages, and if you would do so you would understand how this site works and what the guidelines are here. Rather than getting snarky with me, do what you agreed to do and complete those tasks now. If you don't want to follow the guidelines, feel free to ask your questions somewhere else.

Comment: I'm going to be using this VM to create a website using PHP CODE for the database I'm already familiar with, and I need SQL server to do so. SO IT IS A PROGRAMMING TOOL. SO PLEASE, remove yourself from this thread. Thanks @KenWhite

Comment: You don't get to pick and choose who is involved in comments or answers here, and you don't get to SHOUT at people, and you don't get to post off-topic questions just because you insist you're going to and try to GET LOUD about it. As I said before, read the [help/on-topic], and if you don't want to follow the guidelines feel free to take your questions elsewhere. Questions about your PHP code will be on-topic here, as will questions about SQL for SQL Server.

Comment: You are the most annoying person I've ever run into on here. There are several other questions on here directly related to the question I am asking, just not with the answers I'm looking for. I'm using the virtual machine as a programming tool. And I do get to pick and choose, and ignore you. Bye!